# Presenting an Operator-specific panel to the user

Tags: python, operator, panel

I am trying to write an add-on for an operator that:

1) Links to an external library
2) Displays a list of all the armatures in the linked group
3) Lets the user select a bunch of armatures out of the list
4) Makes proxies for the selected list.

I have managed to write parts 1 and 4, for which I wrote a class:

```
class LinkMakeProxy(bpy.types.Operator):
"""Link & Proxy"""
bl_idname = "bpy.ops"
bl_label = "Link & Proxy"

@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    ...

def execute(self, context):
    ...

def invoke(self, context, event):
    ...
```

but I am not sure how to display the list and get user input.

From reading the API guide, it seems as if I would need to create a new subclass:

```
class SelectArmaturesPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
     """Creates a Panel for Link & Proxy Operator"""
     bl_label = "Select Armatures Panel"
     bl_idname = "TOOL_PT_select_armatures"
     bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
     bl_region_type = 'TOOL_PROPS'
     bl_context = "objectmode"
```

and define a `draw` method for it. My specific questions are:

1) Is this approach correct?
2) How to ensure that the Panel is only shown when the above operator is running?

**Edit**: What I need is something like `bpy.props.BoolVectorProperty` added to my operator class, which I can dynamically set and prompt the user via `context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog` to update. This would do away  with the need for a separate Panel.
The problem with this is `BoolVectorProperty` is of fixed length whereas I need variable length Boolean Vectors.

Comment: What do you mean by "running"? If you just want a dialog that(pop-up) when you operator is executed, you can put a draw function in your operator.

Comment: @cmomoney I need to show the dialog only after getting some info from a file (selected by the user), with the contents of the dialog also based on this info. Is there a way to control all this in the draw function?

Comment: @cmomoney By 'running' I mean while the execute() method is executing.

Comment: You could do this with a CollectionProperty https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_4/bpy.props.html#collection-example

Comment: @cmomoney Thanks for the hint, this looks promising. I asked a related question here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73392/operators-updating-a-collectionproperty-using-the-exec-method