# Operators: Updating a CollectionProperty using the exec() method

Tags: python, properties, operator

I have defined an Operator class which has a `CollectionProperty` like this:

```
class LinkMakeProxy(bpy.types.Operator):
    ...
    my_list = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=BoolProperty)
    ...
```

First, the type of `my_list` is a tuple:

```
(<built-in function CollectionProperty>, {'type': <built-in function BoolProperty>})
```

which I am having trouble wrapping my head around, since I expected some mutable data-structure with data rather than functions.

My question is, how can I access and update this property from the `exec` method of the operator? Similar to what is done in the example given [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_4/bpy.props.html#collection-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *type* parameter of CollectionProperty is expecting a subclass of `bpy.types.PropertyGroup`. So you would need something like:

```
class MyBool(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    bool = BoolProperty()
```

Then in your operator, you use that type in your CollectionProperty:

```
my_list = CollectionProperty(type=MyBool)
```

You add to your collection by using `add()`:

```
mybool = self.my_list.add()
```

...which gives you an instance of the PropertyGroup and the properties it contains. Here is an example that makes a list of booleans based on the selected vertices in the active object and prints the list:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import CollectionProperty, BoolProperty

class MyBool(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    bool = BoolProperty()

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    my_list = CollectionProperty(type=MyBool)

    def execute(self, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        for vert in obj.data.vertices:
            mybool = self.my_list.add()
            mybool.bool = vert.select
        for b in self.my_list:
            print(b.bool)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

register()
```